# blogdown - Set fontsize for code blocks only

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, blogdown

I would like to decrease the font size of the default blogdown Hugo theme but only for code blocks. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There should be a way with css. What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try to adjust `font-size` in the following css block in `main.css`. In my case, I am using lithium-theme.

```
@media
...
.content {
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.8;
  }
```